# How to fix Connection timed out, cURL error 28?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, http, curl

I bought a jobs portal script, I've successfully installed it and when I try to register I get this error:

> cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 2013 milliseconds (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I asked support and they said:

> you need to increase **read_timeout** and **timeout**. The error is clear, you
>   don’t have enough time to get the response. increase time in php.ini

I tried increasing **max_execution_time**, **default_socket_timeout** in php.ini both to 500, but I'm getting the same error. Then I tried manually adding **read_timeout=500** and **timeout=500** and again the same error.

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "tried manually adding read_timeout"? The error message reveals that cURL was only allowed 2 seconds to connect and read the entire response. You set these timeout values to cURL before the request is sent, e.g. in PHP this would be setting `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and/or `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` on the cURL handler, or on the command line, passing `--max-time` and/or `--connect-timeout`.

Comment: Thanks for response, do I set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT in php.ini?

Comment: No, you set it on the curl handler before it's executed. E.g. `$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); [...]; curl_exec($ch) `

Comment: don't know where curl handler is tho

Answer (score 0):

> **CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT (28)**
>
> **Operation timeout. The specified time-out period was reached according to the conditions**

You can set the total time of the cURL transfer using:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
```

Where 500 is the maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

Here is an example of initializing a new cURL session and fetching a web page:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500); 

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: How would this be done on an IIS server?  Specifically, IIS10 on Windows Server 2019?  I am getting the exact same timeout error when using the Facebook Debugger/Scraper tool.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should enable stream_ socket_ server

Answer (score 0):

Use the below mention in your curl request

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```